# Using InfluxDB with interpolate.linear does not output missing values

Tags: influxdb

I have some monthly counter measurements stored inside an InfluxDB instance, e.g. data like this (in line protocol):

```
readings,location=xyz,medium=Electricity,meter=mainMeter energy=13660 1625322660000000000
readings,location=xyz,medium=Electricity,meter=mainMeter energy=13810 1627839610000000000
```

These are monthly readings, not sharp to the beginning of a month (one is at 3rd of July, the other on 1st of August).

My goal it to interpolate these readings on a daily basis, so I stumbled upon the not so well documented `interpolate.linear` function from Flux (https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/flux/stdlib/interpolate/linear/).

But the only output I can generate with my function returns me the two given data values from my input.

```
import "interpolate"
from(bucket: "ManualInput")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "readings")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "energy")
  |> interpolate.linear(every: 1d)
```

Am I missing something here? I've expected to have a linear interpolated value on each day... or is this not possible with Flux? (I'm using V 2.0.7)

Answer (score 0):

I propose to add a yield() function.